# Remove icon only from Winforms top bar and not from Taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons

I have `Winforms` application and the properties `ShowIcon` and `ShowInTaskbat` set to true:

```
this.ShowIcon = true;
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

Currently I can see my application icon in 2 locations:

1. On the task bar (which I want to be).
2. On the top of my application (The place where I want to remove the icon).

If I set the property `ShowIcon` to false I cannot see the icon also in the task bar.
Is it possible to remove the icon only from the application top bar ?

Comment: Hope my answer helped good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the application icon from the project properties form, then it will appear in the taskbar

Answer (score 0):

try setting `FormBorderStyle` to    `FixedToolWindow` or `SizableToolWindow`

or 
you can create your own custom title bars: http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/

Comment: you can use custom titlebars[www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42223/Easy-Customize-Title-Bar)

Answer (score 0):

If you turn it off you need to add the icon as a **resource** and send it to your window.

Example:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

..

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    struct IconHandler
    {
        internal const uint WmSeticon = 0x80u;
        internal const int IconSmall = 0x0;
        internal const int IconBig = 0x1;
    }

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Properties.Resources.Icon.Handle is just an .*ico file in your resources. Icons can have different sizes.
        SendMessage(Handle, IconHandler.WmSeticon, IconHandler.IconSmall, Properties.Resources.Icon.Handle);
        SendMessage(Handle, IconHandler.WmSeticon, IconHandler.IconBig, Properties.Resources.Icon.Handle);
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct. This will show the icon in the title bar regardless of ShowIcon value.